# How to write sql query in cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new in cakephp and i am using cakephp 2.8,I have one sql query and i want to convert into cakephp query,How can i do this ?

Here is my sql query which is working fine in sql but i want to implement in cakphp format,Following is sql query

```
SELECT meta_description.tag_id,meta_description.tag_name,poll_meta.poll_id,polls.content,polls.type,polls.poll_type,polls.user_id,users.username,user_profile.first_name,user_profile.last_name, user_profile.image, user_profile.display_name
FROM meta_description
JOIN poll_meta
ON meta_description.tag_id=poll_meta.tag_id
JOIN polls
ON poll_meta.poll_id=polls.id
JOIN users
ON polls.user_id=users.id
JOIN user_profile
ON users.id=user_profile.user_id
WHERE meta_description.tag_id = ? AND polls.status = 1
            ORDER BY polls.id DESC
```

I tried with following code but this is not working for me,showing error

```
$polls['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'meta_description',
        'alias' => 'BooksTag',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            ' meta_description.tag_id =$tag_id, 
            'polls.status'="1"

        )
    ),
    array('table' => 'poll_meta',
        'alias' => 'poll_meta',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'poll_meta.poll_id = polls.id'
        )
    )

   array('table' => 'users',
        'alias' => 'users',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'polls.user_id = users.id'
        )
    )   
   array('table' => 'user_profile',
        'alias' => 'user_profile',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            ' users.id = user_profile.user_id'
        )
    )   
);

 'order' => array('Poll.date_created' => 'DESC'),
                'limit' => 10

$options['conditions'] = array(
    'meta_description.tag_id' => '$tagid',
    'polls.status' => '1'
);

$polls = $poll->find('all', $options);
```

Above code showing internal server error,How can i remove this , Where i am wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in Cake but there is a PHP syntax error in code, change `' meta_description.tag_id =$tag_id,` to `'meta_description.tag_id ='.$tag_id,` 
remove single inverted commas from variable and try reading error_log file, this kind of all errors are logged there

Comment: Please don't do that, use the `key => value` syntax instead, inserting variable data into a string is a possible SQL injection vulnerability!